# Error while consuming a SOAP web service through a java client,

Tags: java, web-services, soap, junit4, soap-client

I am trying to consume a SOAP web service through a spring web service template.

Steps followed:

1. Generated the source classes from wsdl file using XJC tool.
2. Written a service class which consumes the web service.
3. I am trying to test the service class through a JUnit.

When trying to invoke the web service through the unit, I am getting a java.net.UnKnownhost exception.

I am able to invoke the web service end point URL through SoapUI and through Internet explorer browser.

When I try to invoke the same web service through JUnit, I am getting a java.net.UnknownHostException.

My question is why I am not able to invoke same web service through JUnit?

Comment: I suggest showing us some code, otherwise there will be an awful lot of guessing involved...

Comment: I did some research on my above question and found out that the basic problem is i am not able to hit the web service endpoint url. For example I have an end point urls as "https://example.com/product/info" from which i want to consume the data. When i try to "ping example.com" in windows command prompt I get something like this "Ping request could not find host example.com. Please check the name and try again."  My assumption is if I am able to resolve the ping command problem i,e if I am able to resolve the host then I am good.  Any thoughts in fixing the "ping example.com" issue?

Comment: If you cannot ping the host, then you shouldn't be able to connect there via SoapUI, too. Anyway, if you cannot conntect/ping the host, then there is a problem with your network and probably nothing you can solve via Java.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz: Hi. I am trying to access MS Dynamics NAV Web service through Node-soap but not able to make any request. Any useful hint will be appreciated.